# Question on energies obtained via WKB approximation

Tags: mathematics, approximations

Suppose we are given an ODE problem $$ y''(x)+V(x)f(x)=E_{n} y(x) $$
 with boundary conditions $ y(0)=y(\infty)=0$. Here  $V(x)$ is a potential function.

Then is it always true that (for $n \gg 1$)
$$ E_{n}^{\rm WKB} \sim E_{n} $$

where WKB means the eigenvalues evaluated via the WKB approach?

Comment: And what is the question? Also, isn't the equality of energies suppose to be just approximative (i.e. $\sim$ instead of $=$)?

Comment: I think he is asking whether the WKB bound state energy for the nth bound state converges to the true energy in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: yes, that is as Bebop said, i would like to know if for big big 'n' the approximate energies would converge to the exact ones

Comment: In the equation, the function $f(x)$ should be $y(x)$.